# MS Access Subform in a TabCtl On Load event not triggered

Tags: ms-access, vba

In an Access 2013 project all of the subforms that are hosted within a TabCtl do not get their On Load (or related: Open, Current, Activate, etc) triggered.

The form that hosts the TabCtl does get its On Load called.  Based on a button click it sets the SourceObject property of the Subform control in the TabCtl to the desired form.  The form is displayed, but On Load is never called.

In the same project I do a similar operation (dynamically setting the SourceObject property of a Subform control) but without a  TabCtl involved, and it works as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the subform's displaying properly? What tests have you done on the subform events you say are not working?

Comment: The subforms are all displaying properly.  I have created event procedures for the subform's On Load event, and have put breakpoints, debug messages, message boxes, etc in addition to the non diagnostic code in the On Load event; none of the expected effects are seen.  I am starting to suspect this issue is specific to the Subform being hosted within a TabCtl.